# Django session issue (django-session-security)

Tags: django, django-sessions

i am having an issue with keeping the user logged in (remember me).
I have installed django-session-security and configured the following settings:

```
#SESSION SECURITY SETTINGS
SESSION_SECURITY_WARN_AFTER = 540
SESSION_SECURITY_EXPIRE_AFTER = 600
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.domain.com'
```

Now when a user logs in and has the "remember me" ticked i override the "SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE" setting using this:

```
#Creating the session (no expire/expire) based on choice
if request.POST.get('checkbox', None):
#setting the cookie for a week and overriding the expire at browser close.
#session timing will still be in place.
    request.session.set_expiry(604800)
    settings.SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
else:
    #Session will expire at browser close.
    #session timing will still be in place.
    pass
login(request,user)
```

I see that the cookie is stored with the correct expiration date, but when i close the browser for 15 20 minutes the session disappears.

Am i doing something wrong ?

Thanks for your help!

David

Comment: You can't override settings on a per request basis like that.

Comment: Thank you, what would be the correct way to still have a control of the session duration and have the remember me option working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE=True in your settings file and settings.SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False in your code sometimes these may be creating conflicts.

Comment: Django session security requires that setting to be true for the session expire warning etc...

Comment: I took away SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE=True on the settings and it seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: If the answer has fixed you issue mark it as right one(thats how SO works :D)